# Modern UI for wpf のリンクメニューのフォントを変えたい｡

Tags: c#, wpf

WPF Modern UI というものを使っていますが､画像のメニュー部分のFontFamilyを変える事ができず困っております｡　どなたかご教授ください｡
変更したいフォントはMeiryo UIです｡ 今はOSのデフォルトフォント(Windows 10だとYu Gothinc?)で表示されます｡
参考URL:https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

試した事は
アプリケーション内のXAML内のroot部分(表現の仕方がおかしかったらすみません…)にFontFamilyを指定｡　
→反映されず
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

GitHubでもとのdllのソース内のFontFamily指定部分をMeiryo UIに変更｡
→反映されず
https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui

ご教授よろしくお願いします｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modern UI for WPFのソースを見る限り、`ModernWindow.Template`内の`ModernMenu.Template`に設置されている[`ListBox`の`ItemContainerStyle`](https://github.com/firstfloorsoftware/mui/blob/master/1.0/FirstFloor.ModernUI/Shared/Themes/ModernMenu.xaml#L35)でフォントが明示されているように見えます。ですので通常の方法ではフォントが変更できません。

ライブラリを改変する場合はフォント名を書き換えるだけでも良いのですが、`ModernWindow`と`ModernMenu`にこのフォント用のプロパティを増やし、各テンプレートで値を`ListBox`に受け渡しておくと外部から変更できるようになります。

無理やり外部から変更する場合は、

- `ModernMenu`の既定のスタイルで`Template`を定義しなおす。
- `ModernWindow`のビジュアルツリーから当該`ListBox`を探して`ItemContainerStyle`を変更する。

という方法が考えられます。

Comment: 上記、方法で変更可能でしたありがとうございます。…　というより根本的な原因はdllの配置がよろしく無く、ずっと古いものを参照していました。恥ずかしい限りです。　回答ありがとうございます。